# How make a stretchable image in Cocos2d-x (C++ openGL)

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I'm studying about Cocos2D and OpenGLES.

I want make

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:14.0];

- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

with OpenGL in C++(Cocos2D-x).

So Prototype I want to make will be

```
(CCSprite*) stretchableSpriteWithFile(const char *pszFileName, float leftCap, float topCap, float width, float height);
```

before image : http://postfiles6.naver.net/20091019_85/jun0683_1255941958601C1KQo_png/green_jun0683.png?type=w2

after image : http://postfiles5.naver.net/20091019_84/jun0683_12559419613787bC6n_png/green4_jun0683.png?type=w2

Thank you for your advice.

Tae-ho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one code snippet at http://www.crocodella.com.br/2011/07/resizable-decorated-box-using-cocos2d/
Fixed codes in the comment part of above page are held at https://github.com/jgrimaul/DecoratedBox

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the test projects, in cocos2d-2.0-rc0a-x-2.0/tests running the Android.mk and launching the apk with eclipse (In linux). There are some examples to manage texture and effects.